# MongoDB multiple $and operators query in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I’m having trouble with this MongoDB query using PHP array syntax. This is a direct version of the query I want to use.

```
db.collection.find({
        $or: [
            {$and : [{X:1}, {X: {$gt: 100}}]},
            {$and : [{X:2}, {X: {$lt: 100}}]}
        ]
});
```

*Note: The real query is more complicated, this is just an example.*

I wasn’t able to find some examples describing this kind of query in PHP.
The best I’ve come up was this:

```
$query = array(
    '$or' => array(
        array(
            '$and' => array(
                array('X' => 1),
                array('X' => array('gt' => 100))
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$and' => array(
                array('X' => 2),
                array('X' => array('lt' => 100))
            )
        ),
    )
);

$this->db->collection->find($query);
```

But this query doesn't return any results.
Obviously we can't remove `$and` from the array because we can't have duplicate keys in PHP array.

I don't want to use JavaScript expressions because the speed is critical.

UPDATE: As Alexander Azarov pointed out in comments, my original query can be written differently. I've updated the question with the properly used   `$and` query.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you have error messages?

Comment: The query executes fine but returns 0 results.

Comment: Could you post a sample data dump?

Comment: BTW, @ChristianP , you do not need `$and` here. `{X:1, Y: {$all: [5,6,7]}}` should work.

Comment: Does equivalent query in mongo shell find these records?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The query in mongo shell finds there records ok. But this query doesn't find anything when I try to run it from PHP. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: @ChristianP: I don't know, I'm not a PHP guy :-)

Comment: But, logically thinking, the problem is in your PHP. Either your syntax is off, or the driver doesn't support this kind of queries yet.

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov thanks it works. But then, why the $and operator exists?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It crossed my mind. I didn't found any code examples for this kind of queries so I don't know if this is isn't supported or if my syntax is wrong when I try to use multiple $and operators.

Comment: @ChristianP: `$and` exists for this king of thing: `db.foo.find( { $and: [ { a: 1 }, { a: { $gt: 5 } } ] } )`

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov never mind, I re-read the MongoDB documentation about $and.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example of the code with **or** and **and** operators in PHP for a Mongo query.

It uses different field names from what you are going to find in your query, but it is straightforward to understand how to use it.

Right now I don't have time to change it, to match your query, but if you have problems with that, let me know and I will adjust it. This query is working and finding what it should find.

```
$arrFind = array(
    '$or' => array(
        array(
            '$and' => array(
                array(
                    UI_name => array(
                        '$regex' => 'andrew',
                        '$options' => 'i'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    UI_surname => array(
                        '$regex' => 'mik',
                        '$options' => 'i'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$and' => array(
                array(
                    UI_surname => array(
                        '$regex' => 'andrew',
                        '$options' => 'i'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    UI_name => array(
                        '$regex' => 'mik',
                        '$options' => 'i'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
    )
);
```